# Manjaro doesn't update syslinux.cfg when I install new kernels. How can it be done?

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, upgrade, manjaro, syslinux

I have <strike>a fresh installation of</strike> installed *Manjaro 15.12 (Capella) 64-bit* months ago on my Dell Latitude. I started with the CLI installer as I had a couple of LVM volumes to reattach to my system — such as `/home` and the one with my virtual machines. Those volumes come from an old and deprecated **Linux Mint 16** installation.

I have selected Syslinux as my boot manager. Manjaro update manager however doesn't update my `syslinux.cfg` file whenever I install new kernels using Manjaro Kernel Manager; `syslinux.cfg` has only one entry, `vmlinuz-4.1-x86_64` although I also have the *recommended* (as of today) Linux kernel version **4-4.9-1** installed. Both are marked *installed* but only the older one is marked *in use*.

By the way I couldn't figure out how to *select* other kernels using the GUI tools. Is that expected? Is this operation only done by editing `syslinux.cfg` manually?

**EDIT**: The answer no longer matters (2017-08) to me for I have now reverted to using Gentoo on my computer, for which I have written scripts to do just that.